# Where do passports get mailed from in the United States?

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, us-citizens

I was recently approved for my passport. I was wondering where it will be mailed from (state)?

Comment: You can call the passport agency and ask.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: See [Passport Agencies](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/information/where-to-apply/agencies.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivia question about the operations of the US passport agency that has nothing to do with travel.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [forum](http://forums.immigration.com/threads/where-from-the-new-us-passports-are-mailed.281386/), it seems that passports are mailed from various locations around the US since there are multiple passport processing centers in the US.